# Suggestions on using irobot create with hokuyo urg 04lx / turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if its possible to use hokuyo URG 04LX lidar sensor with the turtlebot or irobot create.The kinect has a limited range of 50 degrees scan. I want to use the hokuyo for larger scans (180-240 degrees).  How do we use the same turtlebot power and sensor board to connect the hokuyo laser? I have seen that people have successfully used arduino with roomba and hokuyo, but has anyone being able to use create / turtlebot successfully and build 2d maps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44660/suggestions-on-using-irobot-create-with-hokuyo-urg-04lx-/-turtlebot?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure, that should work fine. The only thing, you need to do is use 5V instead of the 12V for Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1